# Vue and Vuex v-for not updating properly when state changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, v-for

Here is my store and delete mutation.

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: [
      {
        date: "22/03/1994",
        todos: [
          { icon: 0, text: "seyehate çıkılacak " },
          { icon: 0, text: "seyehate çıkılacak " },
        ]
      },
      .....
    ]
  },

  getters: {
    getTodos: state => {
      return state.todos
    }
  },

  mutations: {
     delete(state, { dateIndex, index }) {
      console.log("dateIndex", dateIndex)
      if (state.todos[dateIndex].todos.length == 1) {
        state.todos.splice(dateIndex, 1)
      } else {
        state.todos[dateIndex].todos.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  },
})
```

This is my main component:

```html
<ListDate
  v-for="(item, index) in list"
  :key="index"
  :todos="item"
  :dateIndex="index"
></ListDate>
```

And I computed data with getters:

```js
computed: {
  list() {
    return this.$store.getters.getTodos;
  },
},
```

and in my ListDate component:

```html
<ListItem
  v-for="(item, index) in dateTodos"
  :key="index"
  :message="item.text"
  :icon="item.icon"
  :dateIndex="dateIndex"
  :index="index"
/>
```

In this component I commit delete mutation. Its work but when I splice with dateIndex its not work correct. I look state and I see its changed but list not render as correct way. when I delete some index suddenly last object gone, state is normal but view not look correct. how I render state data correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `v-for` uses `index` as a `key`, when you delete an item, the next one slides into its place, and the DOM is reused.

You need to create a truly unique property on the objects to use as a key, like an `id`:

```js
todos: [
  { id: 1, icon: 0, text: "seyehate çıkılacak " },
  { id: 2, icon: 0, text: "seyehate çıkılacak " },
]
```

And use that property as the `key`:

```html
<ListItem
  v-for="(item, index) in dateTodos"
  :key="item.id"
  :message="item.text"
  :icon="item.icon"
  :dateIndex="dateIndex"
  :index="index"
/>
```